# How to find if two series intersect?

Tags: algorithm

Consider that i have two series 2,3,4,5,6 and 4,5,6,7,8,9. There are a few numbers in common in these series. What algorithm should I use to write a computer program to find if two given series intersect.

Comment: loops is your answer or move question to : http://mathoverflow.net/

Comment: Are the sequences always sorted, like in the example?

Comment: @Joni Those are not sequences but **series** (assuming that OP's wording is correct) [(this)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Series_(mathematics)), so yes they are.

Comment: @H2CO3 I assume the OP is not a mathematician nor a native English speaker and is using the word incorrectly. It is a very common mistake to confuse series with sequence.

Comment: @H2CO3 Those are not series, those are sequences. A series is a sum over a sequence, and this doesn't say anything about sums. From the values of two series you cannot tell whether they have any common summands.

Comment: @G.Bach Well, can't the series `2, 3, 4, 5, 6` be the sum of the sequence `1, 1, 1, 1, 1`? (Basically that's what I'm saying, but in the belief that OP got the terminology right.)

Comment: @Srivathsan Do you mean infinite sequences, or does each sequence contain only a finite number of non-zero components?

Comment: @H2CO3 No, it can't. If a series is defined, it is only one value (a series is defined iff it is convergent). 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 would be the sequence of the sums of 1, 1, 1, 1, ... up to the i-th component. Thinking in those terms, a series is the limit of the sequence of the sums over a sequence (iff that limit exists).

Comment: @H2CO3 : Should we edit the question then? I'm not an english native speaker and in my language we can say a "serie" of numbers (which is not the math terminology).

Comment: @G.Bach : Ok lets avoid confusion. I would better say it as a list of continuous numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Decision**

```
IF (A.START >= B.START AND A.START <= B.END)
OR (A.END >= B.START AND A.END <= B.END)
OR (B.START >= A.START AND B.START <= A.END)
OR (B.END >= A.START AND B.END <= A.END)
```

**Example**

```
A = { 2,3,4,5,6 }
B = { 4,5,6,7,8,9 }

A.START = 2
A.END = 6

B.START = 4
B.END = 9

(A.END >= B.START AND A.END <= B.END)
6 >= 4 AND 6 <= 9 ~ TRUE
```

Comment: Much smarter and shorter algo. Thanks for it :)

Answer (score 3):

As I catch you have 2 unique already sorted lists.
The idea is to go throw both sorted lists/arrays in the same loop and compare the elements. The iteration will increment only one of indexes in non-match case and skip both indexes if there is a match.
Algorythm is about O(N+M) where N and M the sizes of 2 arrays.
Here is example in JavaScript:

```
var l1 = [2,3,4,5,6];
var l2 = [4,5,6,7,8,9];
var intersection = [];
for (var i1=0,i2=0; i1<l1.length || i2<l2.length;) {
    if (l1[i1] == l2[i2]) {
        intersection.push(l1[i1]);
        ++i1;
        ++i2;
    } else {
        if (l1[i1] < l2[i2]) {
            ++i1;
            if (i1 >= l1.length)
                break;
        } else {
            ++i2;
            if (i2 >= l2.length)
                break;
        }
    }
}
console.log(intersection);
```

Comment: this is what i was going to write ! +1

Comment: Why did you use `OR` in the `for` condition instead of `AND`? This makes you able to remove the ugly `break`s.

Comment: That condition in for statement means to stop only when both series iterations are finished, no other conditions attached. From other hand, those break's in the body have additional conditions to stop in more specific cases.

Comment: if i1 >= l1.length or i2 >= l2.length you *must* stop otherwise you'll try to access an out of bound value. And you can't find any more intersection if one of the list is finished.

Answer (score 1):

In Python you could check in one sequence occurs in another:

```
>>> str(seq1)[1:-1] in str(seq2)
```

It works by removing the `[]`'s from the string representation of seq1 and then seeing if it occurs in seq2:

```
>>> str([1,2,3])
'[1, 2, 3]'
>>> str([1,2,3,4])
'[1, 2, 3, 4]'
```

Comment: It would help to know what language this is (not that I think OP is looking for a language-specific function). Also, doesn't just `[1:]` work?

Comment: Only works if the number are consecutive. And then you have to test in both way.

Answer (score 0):

OP question was to know only *if* two lists intersect. My answers give the common numbers between the two lists that is more general but it only requires to add a boolean and a break to change that.

First, I assume the list are **sorted** but the numbers can be **not consecutive**:

**Solution in C:**

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int l1[] = {2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
    int l2[] = {4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};

    int i1 = 0;
    int i2 = 0;

    while (i1 < 5 && i2 < 6) {
        if (l1[i1] == l2[i2]) {
            printf("%d\n", l1[i1]);
            i1++;
            i2++;
        } else if (l1[i1] < l2[i2]) {
            i1++;
        } else {
            i2++;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**Verified:**

```
 % ./a.out 
4
5
6
```

**Solution in Python:**

```
l1 = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
l2 = [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
i1 = 0
i2 = 0

while i1 < len(l1) and i2 < len(l2):
    if l1[i1] == l2[i2]:
        print(l1[i1])
        i1 += 1
        i2 += 1
    elif l1[i1] < l2[i2]:
        i1 += 1
    else:
        i2 += 1
```

Now, if the lists are **not sorted**, you have three solutions:

- You can loop over the 2 lists and check when both elements are identical: O(n*m)
- You can sort them before in order to use the first algorithm : O(n log n) + O(m log m) + O(n+m)
- You use a hashset (see below) : O(n+m)

See:

```
l1 = [5, 6, 4, 2, 3]
l2 = [8, 6, 5, 7, 4, 9]
i1 = 0
i2 = 0

s1 = set(l1)

for v in l2:
    if v in s1:
        print(v)
```

One could say that the set is not mandatory since I could directly write `v in l1` but with a list it would be the first solution (`in` is linear in time) while using a set the `in` should be almost constant in time. That could be useful with large lists.

**Verified too:**

```
 % python inter.py 
6
5
4
```

And to conclude, if the lists are both **sorted** and **consecutive**, you can conclude whether they intersect or not very easily by comparing the boundaries (see Khaled A Khunaifer answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17420402/1787973):

**In Python:**

```
(l1[0] >= l2[0] and l1[0] <= l2[-1]
or l1[-1] >= l2[0] and l1[-1] <= l2[-1]
or l2[0] >= l1[0] and l2[0] <= l1[-1]
or l2[-1] >= l1[0] and l2[-1] <= l1[-1])
```